# Is there any opencv android function available to replace the pixel values without for loop?

Tags: python, android, opencv, image-processing, contour

I was working on an android based computer vision project. I'm using opencv android SDK to do the image processing stuff. We already created the code in python and started working on android. Now I'm facing an issue when trying to convert the python code into android. I need to replace the pixel values with a new value. If I use for loop and loop through each pixel and modify that, then it is taking too much time because I'm using a high-resolution image.

`img[ mask == 0] = 255`

I need to similar implementation of the above code in android (java).

Comment: You mean Java, right? As far as I know, you can’t  vectorize that operation in Java like you can do it in python via numpy. However, you might try the opencv Java bindings to apply the operation via thresholding or masking.

Comment: Yeah I mean a  java based solution is needed.

Comment: `img.setTo(255, zero_mask)` if the java bindings are anything like the C++ API.